# Протестировать Angular компонент с инжектированным сервисом

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2, angular5, jasmine

Компонент принимает:

- TransformDateService - преобразует дату в специфический формат
- @Input - заходит глубокий массив обьектов.

Внутри компонента массив перебирается, трансформируется, в нужном месте в цикле вызывается сервис.
Мне нужно протестировать шаблон, чтобы обновленные данные правильно вывелись в UI.
Как тестировать такой компонент, использовать реальный сервис или мок? Если мок, то не очень понятно, как его вызвать в цикле для каждого значения. Отдельно сервис сам по себе протестирован.

```
  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class TransformDateService {
  transformDate(data) {
    // Принимает данные и возвращает дату в специфическом формате.
    return date;
    }
  }


  export class Component {
  @Input() tableData;

  constructor(private transformDateService: TransformDateService) { }

  ngOnchanges() {
   if (this.tableData) {
     //преобразования упрощены
     for(const item of this.ngOnchanges) {
     item.date= this.transformDateService(item);
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Сервис нужно замокать. Может быть ситуация, когда сервис будет выполнять запрос на бэкенд - получается, что при тестировании будут выполняться какие-то запросы. Во-вторых, тест компонента должен иметь минимум зависимостей, то есть компонент зависит от сервиса, сервис зависит от других сервисов, и т.д. Получается что тест от компонента зависит от какого-то постороннего сервиса.

Comment: Я не понимаю, концептуально, что должен мок возвращать в моем случае, чтобы для каждого нового входящего в моковый сервис параметра получать свое значение.
В случае с моком сервиса, который делает запрос на сервер, все понятно, мокается ответ сервера. В моем случае моком должна быть функция, копия реального сервиса?